# Two mice pointers (xinput stuff) issue (logs me off)

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, xinput

I'm trying to use two mice (mouse pointers) on my laptop (Linux Mint 16) so I've been following some tutorials that I found: the idea is to work with the xinput command. I have two mice (Touchpad and a wireless one).

So I create a new master

```
xinput --create-master secondmice
```

it seems to work since a new pointer appears on the screen (I can't move it though).

Then I "bind" it to a mouse (the wireless one):

```
xinput reattach ID_WIRELESS ID_SECONDMICE
```

it looks ok for no error occurs.

Once it's done I start moving the mice (wireless) to test. But it immediately crashes and logs me off. When I log back in, everything's alright, but I still have only my one unique pointer. Why does it crashes?

I checked log files and I couldn't find anything "weird" or that might helped me (`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, `/var/log/messages`, `~/.xsessions-errors`...)

EDIT: When it crashes a black-screen shows up (tty), right before I got on the "Log-in page", here's what we can read:
    Linux Mint 16 Petra AslComp tty1
    AslComp: [ 24.263867] brcmsmac bcms0:0: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
    [ 24.264035] brcmsmac brcms0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
"AslComp" is computer name.
I've searched those terms with Google but it's more related to Wifi than xinput.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it crashed but now I got it working because I reattached a different ID. I have 2 physical USB receivers, one for a mouse+keyboard combination and the other for a separate mouse. Maybe you reattached the wrong USB receiver's ID, trying to turn a keyboard into a mouse? I got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I made it working by using:

```
xinput --list --short
```

to find the IDs of the devices and then

```
xinput reattach xx yy
```

Comment: Please explain what *``xx``* and *``yy``* are. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.